# How to generate HDL code without the simulation

Tags: pygears

I would like to generate HDL code without running the simulation. I managed to generate the code, but I had to run the simulation first. However, I would like to do it without this step. Is this possible, and how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, when a module is simulated using a HDL simulator (such as Verilator), running the simulation will automatically generate the HDL code for that purpose.

In order to directly instruct PyGears to generate HDL, you should use `hdlgen()` function which is available via:

```
from pygears.hdl import hdlgen
```

The function supports the following parameters:

- **top** - Path to the module (within the design hierarchy) that should be generated. PyGears uses POSIX like paths, i.e. '/path/to/my/module`
- **lang** - HDL language to use. SystemVerilog: 'sv' and Verilog: 'v' currently supported
- **outdir** - Directory where to place the generated files
- **copy_files** - When set to `True` it will also copy needed files from PyGears library to **outdir**. When set to `False`, you will have to make sure to include the PyGears libraries also when using the generated files.